# SQL Server local variable causing performance problems

Tags: sql-server, local-variables

I'm going to keep this as simple as I can. After hours of debugging, I found out the source of my DRASTIC slowdown.

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 9999

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.FN_Whatever(@Id, NULL, NULL)
```

Execution time : 15 minutes

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.FN_Whatever(9999, NULL, NULL)
```

Execution time : 0 seconds

Please help me understand this frustrating problem...

Here is the function dumbed down a little(private company code so...)

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_Whatever
    (@Id INT,
     @V1 INT = NULL,
     @V2 INT = NULL)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
        SELECT T1.Id, T1.Value
        FROM Table T1
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT X
                   FROM Table T2
                   WHERE Id = @Id
                     AND (@V1 IS NULL OR x = @V1)
                     AND (@V2 IS NULL OR y = @V2)
                   GROUP BY x, y, z) SH_List ON ...
        JOIN 
            FN_2 (@Id, @V1) FN1 ON ...
        WHERE 
            Id = @Id
            AND (@V1 IS NULL OR x = @V1)
            AND (@V2 IS NULL OR y = @V2)
```

Comment: Is there a difference present in the Actual Execution Plans of the queries?

Comment: Post Fn_Whatever ... The second call can be optimized probably, since all parameters are known.

Comment: Have you looked into parameter sniffing?

Comment: @CriticalError I had that kind of problem before, and then just transfered params in other params before using them inside my procedure to solve the problem. But this is before I even get inside the function.... Never saw it happen that way before.

Comment: Would need to see the execution plans before making an even semi-educated guess.

Comment: In that case @stackreader, you'll need to look at your execution plans to see what's happening in both cases. I despise these types of problems.

Comment: @CriticalError so the procedure don't transform the variable to a number before calling the function? I thought both should have the exact same result no matter what... I don't see why the function should have anything to do at all with a local variable from a parent procedure...

Comment: You would "think" there wouldn't be a difference, right? The execution plan will give you insight if there is.